# Windows のイベントログに、再起動に関する「イベントID:7043」が記録されていたが、詳しい情報が分からない

Tags: windows

OS再起動が発生したという事象があり、該当時刻をイベントビューアーを確認したところ
下記のログが記録されていました。

イベントID:7043
update orchestrator service for windows update サービスは、プレシャットダウン コントロールを受け取った後に正しくシャットダウンされませんでした。

ググってみたのですが、いまいちしっくり来るものが見つけられず。
情報をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

[Windows 10 / Windows Server 2016 で イベント ID 7043 (UsoSvc) が発生する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/archive/blogs/jpwsus/win10-7043)
ということなので、これは「更新があった」ことを意味していて、それ以上の意味はないようです。

再起動を必須とする更新があって正しく更新→再起動しただけなのでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！